# SQL server- delete row from table using Trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I have a problem with SQL server, I need to create a trigger that works that way:

Every time when I insert information to **tblNotInterested**  (Inside the table I have two columns "email1" and "email2").
The trigger needs to check if "email1" and "email2" already exists in a different table named **tblListOf**.
If they exist I need to delete the row in which they were found.

Comment: How far have you got with it? Any sample code you need help with?

Comment: What is your effort so far to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like this:

```
DELETE FROM tblListOf 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblNotInterested
WHERE tblNotInterested.email1 = tblListOf.email1 and tblNotInterested.email2 = tblListOf.email2)
```

Comment: I try your solution but unfortunately, it doesn't work. I need to use a trigger and  I don't  understand where is taking a place in your code.

Answer (score 0):

[inserted and deleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables) tables can be quite useful, but they are definitely buyer beware because ...

- they don't always lend themselves to easy documentation
- they are invisible to client applications
- they may have performance, or scalability issues, due to expensive locks

That being said, I believe the below code should work for this case.  One final caution/question may be around nullable columns in your two tables.  If either email1 or email2 is nullable on any table, I would consider re-evaluating this code.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trig_i_tblNotInterested_MatchingEmail1AndEmail2
   ON  dbo.tblNotInterested
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DELETE L
        FROM dbo.tblListOf L
        INNER JOIN inserted ins
            ON L.email1 = ins.email1
            AND L.email2 = ins.email2
END
GO
```